# Meta required tags have a CSS identity crisis on hover

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

When you hover over required tags on meta sites that have said tags styled similarly to the one below, they now lose a pixel from their top and bottom borders:

[image: Hovered required tag]

This is because `a.post-tag:hover` (which defines a one-pixel right and bottom border) is more specific than `.required-tag:hover` where the two-pixel border is defined. This  causes the whole tag list to shift to the left while hovering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently changed the CSS on all the sites to apply the `:hover` styles to `<a>` tags only (so they're not applied in the tag editor). Looks like I missed one spot here (and on meta.sf). Fixed, thanks! (next build yaddayadda)

Comment: Ah, seems that `.post-text .required-tag:hover` needs this treatment too ([example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102181))?

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks. Different issue, same problem. The tag stylings from pre-Jin-awesomeness days have some selector specificity issues.

Comment: The solution must be to create more Jin clones. Although then the bacon expense bill would be enormous.