# Could we merge tags aes-encrypt and aes-256 into aes?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I just found the tag [aes-encrypt](/questions/tagged/aes-encrypt) - it has 83 questions, 23 of them also tagged [aes](/questions/tagged/aes).

From a first skimming of the questions, it looks like some of them might mean some keyword/constant named `AES_ENCRYPT` (in PHP?), and some other want actually specify that they are about the encryption instead of decryption part. (There is no [aes-decrypt](/questions/tagged/aes-decrypt), though.) Most of them simply mean "I want to encrypt using the AES algorithm".

I **think this could be merged** to [aes](/questions/tagged/aes) without any losses.

---

There is also [aes256](/questions/tagged/aes256), which is about the medium-key-length variant of AES (other variants are the common AES-128 and the "very-high-security" AES-512 - but there are no tags for them). 8 of them are also tagged [aes](/questions/tagged/aes) (and 3 [aes-encrypt](/questions/tagged/aes-encrypt), one question has all three tags.)

Some of them are actually about the 256-bit variant, others would be the same for any AES variant (or in fact for any block cipher algorithm).

I think **this could also be merged** with [aes](/questions/tagged/aes) - if not, at least all of these questions should receive an additional [aes](/questions/tagged/aes) tag.

---

Myself having only a score of 3 in the [aes](/questions/tagged/aes) tag, I can't propose these synonyms for the experts to approve, so I'm calling for help here.

Hmm, I should not post [support](/questions/tagged/support) requests on friday evening, they tend to fall down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea -- I merged all your suggestions together.

(I did not set up synonyms; let's see if people stick to [aes](/questions/tagged/aes) like they should.)

Comment: Thanks! (We can see in this question how having the right tag helps getting quick answers ... this got done in 8 minutes after adding the [tag:retag-request] tag, while before it was ignored for a week without this tag.)