# Why do inlined-required-tags change their border-size?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

I just noticed that inlined-required-tags  (in answers/questions) do change their border preferences from

```
border: 2px solid #979797;
```

to

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #565656;
border-right: 1px solid #565656;
```

if you hover over them.

The preview behaves normally. Here, take this inlined tag to test it:

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) a a a a a a a a a a a a

Comment: Looks like a [regression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101398/meta-required-tags-have-a-css-identity-crisis-on-hover/101419#comment263532_101419), even. The `a` in `.post-text a.required-tag:hover` has gone missing again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.